# Position/scale Xamarin.Forms.Shapes PathGeometry as clipping path

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm playing with the new Shapes feature in Xamarin.Forms. I'm trying to clip an image:

```xml
<Image.Clip>
   <PathGeometry 
         Figures="M0,0V517.87c0,25.53,107.53,46.22,240.16,46.22s240.17-20.69,240.17-46.22V0Z" />
</Image.Clip>
```

But the geometry as is, is too big; so I need to scale / move the geometry. Would it be possible?
Thanks

Comment: What do the number mean by 'M0' or '0V517.87c0' ?

Comment: It is svg code.

Comment: Does it really support svg code? If so, I would recommend you to open an issue in Github to get more information.